# Alternate proof for a theorem on ordered fields

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

I came across the following theorem, while studying "A First Course in Real Analysis" by  Berberian Sterling.

In an ordered field, if $a, b, c \geq 0$ and $a \leq b+c$, then
$$ {{a}\over{1+a}} \leq {{b}\over{1+b}} + {{c}\over{1+c}}$$

Here is my proof for this problem.

I first start by proving the following,

**[ T1 ]**: if $x \leq y$ and $x, y > 0$ then ${{x}\over{1+x}} \leq {{y}\over{1+y}}$
$$
x \leq y \implies {{1}\over{x}} \geq {{1}\over{y}} \implies 1+{1 \over x} \geq 1+{1 \over y} \implies {x \over 1+x} \leq {y \over 1+y}
$$

Now considering the right hand side of the statement to be proved
$$
{b \over 1+b} + {c \over 1+c} = {b+c+2bc \over 1+b+c+bc}
$$

From T1, since $a \leq b+c \implies a \leq b+c+bc$ and ${bc \over 1+b+c+bc} > 0$,
$$
{b+c+2bc \over 1+b+c+bc} = {b+c+bc \over 1+b+c+bc} + {bc \over 1+b+c+bc} \geq {b+c+bc \over 1+b+c+bc} \geq {a \over 1+a}
$$

Thus, ${b \over 1+b} + {c \over 1+c} \geq {a \over 1+a}$.

Assuming I have not made any mistakes in the above proof, I would love to know if there is an alternative (and possibly more elegant) way to prove this?

Comment: I don't see how you got the first inequality in the last line above from your previous work; could you please explain that.

Comment: @user84413 The first inequality is based on T1: here (x = a) and (y = b+c).

Comment: Doesn't that give $\frac{a}{1+a}\le\frac{b+c}{1+b+c}$?

Comment: @user84413 I have modified the proof and I have corrected it. I realized that I did not need T2 after all. Thanks for your careful examination.

Comment: It looks good to me. (The only thing you might want to modify slightly is the part of the proof of T1 where you claim that $1/x\ge 1/y$, since this requires $x,y>0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$ is an increasing function.

Thus, if $a \leq b$, then $f(a) \leq f(b) \leq f(b) + f(c)$. Similarly if $a \leq c$.

Now suppose $b \leq a$ and $c \leq a$. Then

$$ \frac{a}{a+1} \leq \frac{b}{a+1} + \frac{c}{a+1} \leq \frac{b}{b+1} + \frac{c}{c+1} $$

---

As an aside, to prove my observation, let $P$ be the statement "$f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on $x \geq 0$". I'm lazy and I already know how to use calculus to prove P, so I don't want to figure out how to do it with algebra (although it's probably pretty easy). Here is my favorite proof method:

As a function on the real numbers, $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 1/(1+x)^2 > 0$, therefore $P$.

$P$ is a semialgebraic (i.e. it can be written in the first-order language of ordered fields). Therefore if it's true in one real closed field (e.g. the real numbers), it's true in *all* real closed fields. (because the theory of real closed fields is complete)

Finally, every ordered field can be embedded in a real closed field. Therefore, $P$ is true in all ordered fields.

Comment: We have $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac1{1+\frac1x}$, and $1/$ reverts the monotonicity (on positive range(!)), while $1+$ doesn't affect it. So it's twisted twice.